# How to find the value of the tolerance d of A.P. a [n]?

Tags: differential-equations

**The known conditions for the question are as follows:**

The tolerance of Arithmetic progression {a [n]} is d, and d>1. Let b [n]==(n ^ 2+n)/a [n]

Moreover, the sequence b [n] is also a Arithmetic progression, S [n] and T [n] are the sum of the first n terms of the sequence a [n] and b [n] respectively.

If S [99] - T [99]==99, calculate the value of the tolerance d of the Arithmetic progression a [n]?

Attempting the following method did not solve d

```
ClearAll["`*"]
FindInstance[{(n^2 + n)/a[n] - ((n - 1)^2 + n - 1)/
    a[n - 1] == ((n + 1)^2 + n + 1)/a[n + 1] - (n^2 + n)/a[n], 
  b[n] == (n^2 + n)/a[n], 
  Sum[a[n], {n, 1, 99}] - Sum[b[n], {n, 1, 99}] == 99, 
  a[n] - a[n - 1] == d, d > 1, a[1] b[1] == 2}, {d, a[1], b[1]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Clear[a];
a[n_] = RSolveValue[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + d, a[1] == a1}, a[n], n]

(* a1 - d + d n *)

b[n_] = (n^2 + n)/a[n]

(* (n + n^2)/(a1 - d + d n) *)

diff[d_, a1_] = Sum[a[n], {n, 1, 99}] - Sum[b[n], {n, 1, 99}];

Plot3D[{diff[d, a1], 99}, {d, 105/100, 110/100}, {a1, 0, 1/50},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

```
d[a1_?NumericQ] := NArgMin[
   {(diff[d, a1] - 99)^2, 105/100 < d < 110/100}, d,
   WorkingPrecision -> 50] // N

d[5/1000]

(* 1.0835 *)

With[{a1 = 5/1000}, diff[d[a1], a1]]

(* 99. *)
```